# PyQt5- Add Custom QComboBox to Pop up Window

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have created a custom class inherited from `QCombobox()` as part of my main application which works fine. I now want to add the same widget to another window upon clicking the `ChangeAttributesButton()` (`QPushButton()`). Relevant snippets of code below.

```
import sys, os, glob
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QLabel, QMdiSubWindow, 
    QMainWindow, QAction, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QComboBox)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal, QObject
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface
        self.canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        self.project = QgsProject.instance()
        self.setWindowTitle('Marker')

        #add toolbar
        self.toolbar = QToolBar("Grade Marker Toolbar")
        self.toolbar.setIconSize(QSize(20,20))
        self.addToolBar(self.toolbar)

        self.SelectCategoryComboBox = SelectCategoryComboBox()
        self.toolbar.addWidget(self.SelectCategoryComboBox)
        self.toolbar.addSeparator()  

        self.ChangeAttributesButton = ChangeAttributesButton(self.canvas)
        self.ChangeAttributesButton.setIcon(QIcon(r'abc.png'))
        self.ChangeAttributesButton.setIconText('Change Grade')
        self.toolbar.addWidget(self.ChangeAttributesButton)
        self.toolbar.addSeparator()
        self.ChangeAttributesButton.clicked.connect(self.ChangeAttributesButton.on_click)

class SelectCategoryComboBox(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SelectCategoryComboBox, self).__init__()
        self.setEnabled(True)
        categories = ['Select Category',"A+","A", "B", "C", "F" ]
        for cat in categories:
            self.addItem(cat)
```

The bit that is causing a problem is here:

```
class ChangeAttributesButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self,canvas):
        super(ChangeAttributesButton, self).__init__()
        self.setEnabled(True)
        self.canvas = canvas

    def on_click(self,state):
        window = ChangeAttributesWindow()

class ChangeAttributesWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ChangeAttributesWindow, self).__init__()
        self.title = 'Change Feature Attributes'
        category_box = SelectCategoryComboBox()
        self.addWidget(category_box)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
```

I am getting

```
AttributeError: 'ChangeAttributesWindow' object has no attribute 'addWidget'`. I have tried changing the parent class of `ChangeAttributesWindow()
```

to

```
QMdiSubWindow()
```

and `QMainWindow()` but I still get an error in the same vein.

How do I add an instance of `SelectCategoryComboBox()` to a child or pop up window?

This is the complete error:

[image]

Comment: please provide a [mre] and show the complete error message.

Comment: mmm, how strange, your code does not match the error message since in the second it indicates that the error is in line `self.afddWidget(category_box)` but in your code I only see `self.AddAction(category_box)`.

Comment: sorry i was trying different methods to try get it to work- i have corrected the code so that it represents the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A QWidget does not have any method called addWidget() so this error is thrown.

If you want to add a widget to a window, you can add it:

- Setting the parent of the widget to the window.

```py
class ChangeAttributesWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ChangeAttributesWindow, self).__init__()
        self.title = 'Change Feature Attributes'
        category_box = SelectCategoryComboBox()
        category_box.setParent(self)
        category_box.move(30, 30)
        self.initUI()
```

- Use a layout established in the window.

```py
class ChangeAttributesWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ChangeAttributesWindow, self).__init__()
        self.title = 'Change Feature Attributes'
        category_box = SelectCategoryComboBox()
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(category_box)
        self.initUI()
```